# Codeigniter 3 blogging application bug: update_post function modifies created_at database table column

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am working on a basic blog application with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **Bootstrap 4**.

In my **Posts_model** model, I have this chunk of code responsible for inserting a new post in the database:

```
public function create_post($post_image, $slug) {
    $data = [
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'description' => $this->input->post('desc'),
        'content' => $this->input->post('body'),
        'post_image' => $post_image,
        'author_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
        'cat_id' => $this->input->post('category'),
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];
    return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
}
```

This function is used in the **Posts** controller: `$this->Posts_model->create_post($post_image, $slug);`.

The update mechanism is similar. In my **Posts_model** model:

```
public function update_post($id, $post_image, $slug) {
    $data = [
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'description' => $this->input->post('desc'),
        'content' => $this->input->post('body'),
        'post_image' => $post_image,
        'cat_id' => $this->input->post('category'),
        'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->update('posts', $data);
}
```

This above function is used in the **Posts** controller like this: `$this->Posts_model->update_post($id, $post_image, $slug);`.

**The problem**

For a reason, I have been unable to identify, whenever I *update* a post, the *created_at* column of the `posts` table is also updated. In other words, the columns *created_at* and *updated_at* have the same value. Why does that happen?

Comment: if data type of `created_at` is `timestamp` and `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` then it will update on every change.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra What shall I change it to?

Comment: have you checked field type ?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Yes, it is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I use migrations to create the tables. For the posts table I have: `'updated_at'=>array(
        'type'=>'TIMESTAMP',
      ),`. What shall I change that to?

Comment: then change it to, `type` => `datetime` and `default` => `none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run these query in phpmyadmin

Here change data type of `created_at` from `timestamp` to `datetime` and assing default value as `null` or `none` you can give anyone you want, here i set `NULL`

```
ALTER TABLE `posts` CHANGE `created_at` `created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: That is at the mySQL level. But how about the migration? Have a look at the "original" **[migration file](https://github.com/Ajax30/lightblog/blob/master/application/migrations/003_create_posts.php)** please.

Comment: you can change same thing in your migration file.